# Using Sinon to test node function without executing the service call within

Tags: node.js, sinon

I'm trying to write tests for my code (simple version of what i'd like to test below), and use sinon and chai to test other things but do not know how to write my tests to mock a service call so that I can avoid making calls out to external services, but get a simulated results set back so that I can process the data. Would I use rewire (and if so how would that work)? Any assistance would be appreciated!

```
qf = require('./service/queryFile');

function countByDate(req, res, next){
    //do stuff to create variable to pass to service call
    var queryCriterion = {
        d1 = req.query.d1,
        d2 = req.query.d2
    }

    //make service call and process results
    qf.getByDateAsync(queryCriterion)
    .then(function(results){
        var data = {};
        //do some things with results data
        data = results.data;

        //return data object
        res.json({
            success: true,
            data: data,
        });
    });
}

module.exports = {
    countByDate: countByDate
};
```

****Additional Details****

The queryFile:

```
function getByDate(criterion){
    //query from database
    //process results
    return {
        key1: aValue,
        key2: bValue,
        data: arrayOfObjects
    };
}

exports = module.exports = {
    getByDate: getByDate,
    getByDateAsync: Promise.promisify(getByDate)
};
```

The test:

```
var pf = require('./service/processFile');
var qf = require('./service/queryFile');
var req, res;

before(function(){
    this.timeout(30000);
});

beforeEach(function(){
    res.json = sinon.spy();
    res.status = sinon.stub().returns({json: sinon.spy()});
});

describe('test', function(){
    it('should return results from countByDate', function(done){
        var eDate = new Date();
        var sDate = eDate.getDate()-60;

        req = res = {};

        req.query = {
            d1: sDate,
            d2: eDate
        };

        var testData = [{
            key1: '',
            key2: '',
            data: [{aKey: new Date(), count: 100}]
        }];

        sinon.stub(qf, 'getByDateAsync').returns(Promise.resolve({data:tData}));

        pf.countByDate(req,res);

        console.log(res.json.data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have required queryFile in my test, and then stubbed the getByDateAsync by returning a promise with a mocked response.

```
const qf = require('./service/queryFile');

sinon.stub(qf, 'getByDateAsync').returns(Promise.resolve({ data: {}}));
```

Comment: I've tried this and the test fails, receiving an error "before each" hook...
TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property getByDateAsync as function.

Comment: Then your qf file doesn't expose that method, and your code doesn't run at all.

Comment: Made some changes, and added some more detail... Error now tells me that on this line: qf.getByDateAsync(queryCriterion)
TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: I think you are missing some pieces. You have a synchronous "getByDate" function but you are trying to mock getByDateAsync. Are you using promisify or something similar? Seems like you're doing things harder than it has to be.

Comment: Thanks for the help.... I will update the question to show the solution. You were right to suggest the qf did not expose the method. I was not realizing that the qf needed to expose a getByDateAsync that returned a promised getByDate, though there is likely a better way to handle all this.